# Is there a way to create two independent layouts in Qt Designer?

Tags: qt, layout, pyqt5, widget

I am new to Qt Designer so this question may be stupid but I'm really stucked.

I'm creating an app using Qt Designer and PyQt5. My app contains a few screens and I want to switch between them by clicking the button.

The first screen consists of a button (button_1) and a label (label_1) placed in a vertical layout. The second screen also consist of a button (button_2) and  a label (label_2), but these are different widgets with different size and content.  And I want to place button_2 and label_2 in a horizontal layout.

Previously I didn't use layouts. I just created one .ui file and put button_2 and label_2 above button_1 and label_1. They were overlapping but it didn't affect the performance because I made the button_2 and label_2 invisible when button_1 and label_1 are shown and vice versa. But now I need to make the window resizable, and I need to put the widgets in a layout.

The first thought was to create two separate .ui files and set them using loadUi command when it comes to switching between screens. But I need to use just one .ui file. Is this possible? How can I create two independent layouts? Or maybe there is another way to solve my proble. Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You can add 2 layouts into 1 parent layout using `addLayout()`, but this is in code, I think it should be also available in designer.

Comment: @NgocMinhNguyen this way I can't overlap widgets, e.g. I won't be able to put button_2 above button_1.

Comment: That is my bad. I didn't read your question carefully. You can consider using `QTabWidget` together with `QStackedWidget` for that purpose.

Comment: @NgocMinhNguyen It's okay, thank you for the suggestion. I could use QTabWidget or QStackedWidget but I want user to switch between screens only using my widgets (button_1 and button_2). My idea is that the user is not supposed to see arrows in QStackedWidget or tab bar in QTabWidget. If there's a way to hide them then this solution would be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that in this case your best option is to use a `QStackedWidget` as a container for your labels and buttons. To create a stacked widget in Qt Designer you can drag a Stacked Widget from the container group on the left to the parent widget. This will create a stack with two pages. Each page can then be set up independently. Whatever layout you and widgets you add to a particular page will only be visible when that page is shown. You can add additional pages if you like by right-clicking on the stacked widget and selecting Insert Page from the context menu.

To navigate between the pages in Qt Designer you can choose the correct widget in the tree in the Object Inspector, use the two black arrows in the top-right corner of the stacked widget, or use the context menu of the stacked widget. To navigate between the pages in your python script you would need to use `QStackedWidget.setCurrentIndex()`.

Comment: Using QStackedWidget works for me I think, but when the app is running I'd like to switch between pages (e.g. my screens) only using my widgets (button_1 and button_2) and to hide those black arrows. Can I do that? Searched for StyleSheet options for QStackedWidget but didn't find any solution. Anyway thank you a lot.

Comment: Those arrows should only be present in Qt Designer itself, not in the final app.

Comment: didn't know that, the arrows were visible when I previewed the .ui file in Qt Designer. But when I run the app they're hidden. Works perfect. Thank you!